# Unity and Repository pattern

Tags: unity-container, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

Hi I am using a UOW and Repository pattern in my project and I have created the following code:

```
// Interfaces
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IGenericRepository<Company> CompanyRepository { get; }
    void Commit();
}

public interface IEFUOW_Company : IUnitOfWork
{
    bool CreateCompanyForUser(RegisterModel model, string userName);
}

// Implementation
public class EFUOW_Company : EfUnitOfWork
{
    public EFUOW_Company()
    {
    }
}

public class EfUnitOfWork : Disposable, IUnitOfWork
{
    private DALDbContext _dataContext;
    private EfGenericRepository<Company> _companyRepo;
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    public EfUnitOfWork()
    {
        _companyRepo = null;
    }
}

// Unity Registration
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, EfUnitOfWork>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IUnitOfWork>());
         .RegisterType<IEFUOW_Company, EFUOW_Company>(new HttpContextLifetimeManager<IEFUOW_Company>());


// Error Message @ Compile

Error   105 The type 'DataAccessLayer.UnitOfWork.EFUOW_Company' cannot be used as type parameter 'TTo' in the generic type or method 
'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType<TFrom,TTo>(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.L
ifetimeManager, params Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InjectionMember[])'. There is no implicit reference conversion from '
DataAccessLayer.UnitOfWork.EFUOW_Company' to 'DataAccessLayer.UnitOfWork.IEFUOW_Company'.
```

I cannot work out why it's complaining about the conversion as I am new to Unity and this is my first attempt at building this type of logic.

I want to be able to create different `IUnitOfWork` based interfaces/implementations so I can reuse code in the `IUnitOfwork` and it's Implementation `EfUnitOfWork`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Grish - please do not edit the question, you have not changed anything !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class efuow_company does not implement iefuow_company interface.

Comment: Thanks Dave, you're a life saver - I not see the forest for the trees